# How do I change the extension of multiple files recursively?

Tags: replace, rename

i have .htaccess.bak, .htaccess files in my webdirectory.

I want to recursively replace the .htaccess.bak to .htaccess

```
./test.com/.htaccess.bak
./test.com/.htaccess
./test.com/application/.htaccess.bak
./test.com/application/.htaccess
```

Comment: or remove the .htaccess file and move the .htacess.bak file to .htaccess recursively

Comment: What's your environment?  What have you tried?

Comment: its a linux machine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have permission to write to each directory, this should work on just about any system except windows.

```
cd webdirectory
find . -name .htaccess.bak | ( while read filename; do
d=`dirname "$filename"`
mv "$filename" "$d/.htaccess"
chmod 600 "$d/.htaccess" # if the perms aren't quite right on .htaccess.bak
done
)
```

It could fail, though, if any pathname component that is found contains the `"` character. If it does, then you can use find's "cd to the directory" option and then you could do something like this:

```
find . -name .htaccess.bak -execdir mv {} .htaccess \;
```

On linux and macOS, the `find` command has the `-execdir` option in addition to the `-exec` option.